# jQuery UI Sortable: Trying to setup sortable but it seems the empty container does not take

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

so I have this partially working sortable UI.  You can see in the fiddle that sorting works within its own column but I also need to be able to have the item be able to sort across columns.  Even to the empty far right column.

Is there any solution to this?

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <div class="item">999</div>
            <div class="item">111</div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">
            <div class="item">888</div>
            <div class="item">yyy</div>
        </div>

        <div class="column">

        </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JS:

```
$( '.wrapper .row' ).each( function() {
    var column = $( '.column', this );

    column.sortable( {
        items: '.item'
    } );
} );
```

Here is a link -> http://jsfiddle.net/KaXJt/1/

Comment: Yeah that would suck if I have to load all 3 plugins just to perform this sortable thing...But if I must, I must...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sortable columns have to be aware of each other.

Here is a demo of how to do it:  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/LfrbC/)

An example from jQuery api [docs](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

Code:

```
$( '.wrapper .row' ).each( function() {
    var column = $( '.column', this );

    column.sortable( {
        items: '.item',
        connectWith:".column"
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Knew I should of read the API more deeply!!  Thanks for that!